# member <method> cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Tags: c#, class

Class File:

```
public class ServiceAccess
{
    public DataTable GetAllShortCodes()
    {
        DataTable ShortCodeTable = new DataTable();
        // logic to add data to Datatable
        return ShortCodeTable;
    }
}
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = ServiceAccess.GetAllShortCodes();
    }
```

Been doing VB for a long time, but new to C#.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to call a static method like it's an instance method somewhere

Comment: Understood.  So... what is the right way to do this?  :-)

Comment: I don't understand from your code if GetAllShortCodes should be static, but you should call it like `instance.GetAllShortCodes()` if it's an instance or define it `static`

Comment: What you have in your question shouldn't cause the error you're getting. The error in your title is about calling a static method as if it's an instance method. What you're doing in your code is calling an instance method as if it's a static method. Can you please check whether you copied the wrong code and/or error message?

Comment: @hvd Yeah, that's what I though, it's one thing in the question title and absolutely different in question body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `GetAllShortCodes` like a static method

you need to change it to this

```
var service = new ServiceAccess();
DataTable dt = service.GetAllShortCodes();
```

or changing the method to a static method as

```
public static DataTable GetAllShortCodes()
{
    DataTable ShortCodeTable = new DataTable();
    // logic to add data to Datatable
    return ShortCodeTable;
}
```

Comment: ok, so what is the right way to call it?  I've tries adding "static" to GetAllShortCodes.  That doesn't work either.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston "That doesn't work either" lies.  Filthy lies.  Prove me wrong!  You should learn the distinction between instance members and static members.  My advice to new C# devs is to pick up CLR Via C#.  Skip chapters 1 and 2 and start reading on chapter 3.  You'll be way ahead of the game in no time.

Comment: Huh... look at that.  When I add "static" to the class method, originally the error persisted, but then I did a build, and it went away.  You were right :-)